# Responsive typography using vw?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a header title scale to the correct font size fluidly. From desktop to mobile. Would using vw the correct approach? If so does anyone have a cheat sheet on how I can accomplish a responsive header?

```
.responsive-header {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

<Title className="responsive-header">
   Resonsive header. Should shrink depending on screen size
</Title>
```

[image: Edit competent-banach-1ymic]

Comment: Use vw if you want it to be exactly the same relative to the width, at all sizes.

Comment: Based on your CodeSandbox there, it's potentially kinda weird if your header were changing size like that, with 2vw, but the rest of your ui isn't...

Comment: I think you would want to read this: https://css-tricks.com/books/volume-i/scale-typography-screen-size/

Answer (score 0):

Use of rem's and Em's been standardized for font size in responsive design. So you might wanna use either of them instead. 
Learn more about Relative lengths [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

While your code might just do it. But how I might make my responsive header is

```
.responsive-header {
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

<Title className="responsive-header">
   Resonsive header. Should shrink depending on screen size
</Title>
```